# Error occurred during initialization of boot layer FindException: Module not found

Tags: java, java-9, java-module

Executing a simple "Hello World" program using Java 9 results in the following error message:

> Error occurred during initialization of boot layer
>   java.lang.module.FindException: Module com.pantech.myModule not found

The command line that I executed was:

```
java --module-path bin -m com.pantech.myModule/com.pantech.myModule.HelloWorld
```

This command line is executed from the parent directory of my `bin` directory that contains all of the `.class` bytecode files.

The `module-info.class` file is located in the `com.pantech.myModule` directory that is located in the `bin` directory. The `HelloWorld.class` file contains the main method and is located in the package directory within the `com.pantech.myModule` directory. Therefore, the pathname of the `HelloWorld.class` file is ***bin\com.pantech.myModule\com\pantech\myModule\HelloWorld.class***.

The `HelloWorld` class is in the `com.pantech.myModule` package (package name same as the module name).

I am using Windows 10 as the Operating System. From everything that I have read, the above command line should be correct. Any suggestions on how to fix this?

Comment: In which directory is the compiled module file? Seems like the directory you need to add to module path is `bin\com.pantech.myModule`

Comment: The compiled module file (module-info.class) is located in the bin\com.pantech.myModule directory.

Comment: Could you share the class definition(starting from package declaration) and module definition as well, for the above to be reproduced, please? And honestly, for such experiments, I take [the quick-start here](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/jigsaw/quick-start) for reference. (you might want to cross verify the compilation commands as well)

Comment: Module definition file (module-info.java) located incom.pantech.myModule directory contains the following: module myModule {}  The source code for the HelloWorld file contains the following:
package com.pantech.myModule;
public class HelloWorld {
   public static void main(String [] args) {
      System.out.println("Hello World from module");
   }
}

Comment: @D.Pante The [answer by tretegfdg](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49546098/1746118) seems to be pointing out the mistake you made. That's why I suggest referring to the guide as well. The module name there is same as the package name `com.greetings`(in the sample), hence their command works. Also, refer to https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/tools/java.htm for more details on the commands used.

Comment: In Netbeans, I just used `Clean and Rebuild Project` and it worked.

Answer (score 24):

The reason behind this is that meanwhile creating your own class, you had also accepted to create a default class as prescribed by your IDE and after writing your code in your own class, you are getting such an error. In order to eliminate this, go to the PROJECT folder → `src` → Default package. Keep only one class (in which you had written code) and delete others.

After that, run your program and it will definitely run without any error.

Answer (score 11):

I had the same issue while executing my selenium tests and I removed the selenium dependencies from the ModulePath to ClassPath under Build path in eclipse and it worked!

Comment: I faced the same issues and this fixed it

Comment: thanks Ankur, did the same and issue got fixed.

Answer (score 9):

I had similar issue, the problem I faced was I added the `selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59.jar` under `modulepath` instead it should be under `classpath`

so select `classpath` via `(project -> Properties -> Java Bbuild Path -> Libraries)`
add the downloaded latest [jar](https://www.selenium.dev/downloads/)

After adding it must be something like this

[image]

And appropriate driver for browser has to be downloaded for me i checked and downloaded the same version of chrom for chrome [driver](https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads) and added in the C:\Program Files\Java

And following is the code that worked fine for me

```
public class TestuiAautomation {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println("Jai Ganesha");
        try {
            System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Program Files\\Java\\chromedriver.exe");
            System.out.println(System.getProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver"));
            ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
            chromeOptions.addArguments("no-sandbox");
            chromeOptions.addArguments("--test-type");
            chromeOptions.addArguments("disable-extensions");
            chromeOptions.addArguments("--start-maximized");
            WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions);
            driver.get("https://www.google.com");
            System.out.println("Google is selected");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println(e);
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

You say that your `module-info.java` contains

```
module myModule {}
```

That means it declares a module called `myModule`, **not** `com.pantech.myModule`. Pointing this from the command format:

```
 -m <module-name>/<main-class>
```

Comment: Thanks.  The problem was solved by changing the module name in the module-info.java file to com.pantech.myModule instead of just myModule.  The solution should have been obvious to me, but I guess that I was looking for something more obscure.

Comment: Can you please explain? I am still not able to figure out what changes i am supposed to make.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue and I fixed it this way:

1. Deleted all projects from eclipse, not from the computer.
2. Created a new project and as soon as you write the name of your project, you get another window, in which is written: "Create module-info.java". I just clicked "don't create".
3. Created a package. Let us call the package `mywork`.
4. Created a Java class inside the package `myWork`. Let us call the class `HelloWorld`.
5. I run the file normally and it was working fine.

Note: First, make sure that Java is running properly using the CMD command in that way you will understand the problem is on eclipse and not on JDK.

Answer (score 2):

I solved this issue by going into Properties -> Java Build Path and reordering my source folder so it was above the JRE System Library.

Comment: Tries Same thing but it does not resolve the error

Answer (score 0):

I just encountered the same issue after adding the bin folder to .gitignore, not sure if that caused the issue.

I solved it by going to Project/Properties/Build Path and I removed the scr folder and added it again.

Answer (score 0):

check your project build in jdk 9 or not above that eclipse is having some issues with the modules. Change it to jdk 9 then it will run fine

Answer (score 0):

This problem occurred for me after deleting my bin folder in order to get it out of my git history. To fix it
In Eclipse:

1. Delete the project (from Eclipse, not from disk)
2. Reimport it.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the JRE System Library from the Java build path of the project. Then add that again under the Modules by clicking Add Library.

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with this too in Eclipse and everything was working fine on the command-line but I kept getting a "module not found" when run in Eclipse. When I found the "Use 'release' option" under Java Compiler and ensured it is ticked then the app runs fine in Eclipse. That's using J17 and Eclipse 2022.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have had a similar situation when I have imported an existing project. So, go to *Run configurations*, and create a **new** run configuration instead of replacing or reusing an exisitng one. the old running configuration may create the problem.

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar problem when for the default package. Just add a package and move your main class to it, and maybe this will resolve your problems.

Answer (score -3):

I faced same problem when I updated the Java version to 12.x. I was executing my project through Eclipse IDE. I am not sure whether this error is caused by compatibility issues.

However, I removed 12.x from my system and installed 8.x and my project started working fine.