# Error occurred during initialization of boot layer : Unable to derive module descriptor error with Selenium and java

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

When I tried to set up selenium in eclipse, after adding jar files, while running the program , I am getting the below error:

```
Error occurred during initialization of boot layer
java.lang.module.FindException: Unable to derive module descriptor for C:\Program Files\Selenium\Lib\selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59 (2).jar
Caused by: java.lang.module.InvalidModuleDescriptorException: Provider class org.eclipse.jetty.http.Http1FieldPreEncoder not in module.
```

Answer (score 2):

I had similar issue, the problem i faced was i added the selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59.jar under modulepath instead it should be under classpath

so select classpath via (project -> Properties -> Java Bbuild Path -> Libraries)
add the downloaded latest [jar](https://www.selenium.dev/downloads/)

After adding it must be something like this

[image]

And an appropriate driver for browser has to be downloaded for me i checked and downloaded the same version of chrome for chrome [driver](https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads) and added in the C:\Program Files\Java

And following is the code that worked fine for me

```
    public class TestuiAautomation {

        public static void main(String[] args) {

            System.out.println("Jai Ganesha");
            try {
                System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Program Files\\Java\\chromedriver.exe");
                System.out.println(System.getProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver"));
                ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
                chromeOptions.addArguments("no-sandbox");
                chromeOptions.addArguments("--test-type");
                chromeOptions.addArguments("disable-extensions");
                chromeOptions.addArguments("--start-maximized");
                WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions);
                driver.get("https://www.google.com");
                System.out.println("Google is selected");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.err.println(e);
            }

        }

    }
```

For [reference](https://dunnsolutions.com/digital-solutions-blog/-/blogs/installation-and-configuration-of-selenium-webdriver)

and check for the browser version and chromedriver version

Answer (score 0):

This error message...

```
Error occurred during initialization of boot layer
java.lang.module.FindException: Unable to derive module descriptor for C:\Program Files\Selenium\Lib\selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59 (2).jar
Caused by: java.lang.module.InvalidModuleDescriptorException: Provider class org.eclipse.jetty.http.Http1FieldPreEncoder not in module.
```

...implies that the *Java Compiler* was unable to compile the program due to InvalidModuleDescriptor.

Possibly your main issue is the **incompatibility** between the version of the binaries as either you are using *Java v9*, *Java v10* or *Java v11*.

---

### Solution

Uninstall the existing *JDK v9* / *Java v10* / *JDK v11* and install the latest *Java v8*, i.e. [JDK 8u212](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html)

> You can find a detailed discussion in [Unable to import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver using Selenium and Java 11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54876955/unable-to-import-org-openqa-selenium-webdriver-using-selenium-and-java-11/54880228#54880228)

Comment: +1 for asking a good question, and  -1 for suggesting reverting back to an older (pre-modules) version of Java. That's just bad advice :( For "better" solutions, look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49520858) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63877831/421195)