# Why am I getting this error in eclipse involving initialization of boot layer?

Tags: java, eclipse

I am trying to set up my eclipse environment for the sedgewick algorithms course and I keep receiving the following error:

```
Error occurred during initialization of boot layer
java.lang.module.FindException: Unable to derive module descriptor for /home/yannik/algs4/algs4.jar
Caused by: java.lang.module.InvalidModuleDescriptorException: TestAlgs4.class found in top-level directory (unnamed package not allowed in module)
```

Why is this happening and how do I fix this?

And the image is attached. I created a class Rational under the default package in source.

[image]

Comment: already deleted it and still didn't work.

Comment: Seems like you're putting a library that was built before modules on the module-path. That makes it an automatic module and as such is subject to the rules of the module system (e.g. no classes in the unnamed package). You can try placing the library on the class-path instead.