# why can't Eclipse connect to VM? (socket closed)

Tags: java, eclipse, exception, error-handling, virtual-machine

the console won't run the program. nothing i do works.
even when i'm trying to run the most simple program it still won't work and it always gives me the same error.
1. a pop up error window saying "Cannot connect to VM - Socket closed"
2. java.lang.module.FindException: Module guy not found

what can i do to solve the problem?

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49520858/error-occurred-during-initialization-of-boot-layer-findexception-module-not-fou might be belpful

Answer (score 0):

You first have to fix all compile errors to be able to launch it.

Currently, the code can not be compiled because `try` is a keyword in Java and therefore cannot be used as a variable name.