# Got error:jdk.management.agent not found when running a new springboot app

Tags: java, spring-boot

Error occurred during initialization of boot layer
java.lang.module.FindException: Module jdk.management.agent not found
when create a new springboot app using eclipse and run it.

Comment: JRE15, eclipse, spring tool 4 suite

Comment: already answer you can refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49520858/error-occurred-during-initialization-of-boot-layer-findexception-module-not-fou

Answer (score 0):

sovled!
if using jdk 15, right click your project->build path-> configure build path->libraries-> remove your JRE 15, and add JRE14(but can still be jdk15).